# How to add Currency switcher in footer using magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, currency, footer

i want to add Currency switcher in footer section.

Answer (score 2):

Override default.xml file in your current theme and add below code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="currency" before="store_language" template="currency.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Run `setup:upgrade` command and clear cache

Comment: mansi , thank you for your reply but it is not working i have already tried this and can u suggest me another method to display?.

Comment: mansi, thank you for your reply and it is working ....cache issue so when i cleared it was working.